# How to Redirect to Page With Fixed Navbar and Scroll Down to DIV

Tags: php, html, css, url

I redirect users from a page onto another page on my website.  I redirect using the following URL format:

> locations.php?id=1#resultsbox_10

The above will take the user to the DIV 'resultsbox_10'.  I recently made changes to my navbar so that it sticks to the top 100px of the webpage when you scroll down.  I used the JQuery Waypoints plugin.  Since the first 100px of my page is now covered by the navbar, part of the DIV that the user is redirected to has been blocked.  Is there a way for me to take the user to DIV 'resultsbox_10' plus 100px from the top by adding something to the URL?

Comment: Can you not just add padding to the top of resultsbox_10 and push the content down?

Comment: @Liam There are multiple resultsboxes on the page.  They are presented as a list.  If you add padding to each resultsbox, you would have a lot of extra space when viewing the page normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a JavaScript answer for this dilemma after drinking a whole thing of Gatorade tonight.  Instead of passing the DIV id through the URL, I pass a GET variable.

```
locations.php?id=1&link_review_id=66
```

On my target page ("locations.php"), I grab the GET value.

```
$link_review_id = $_GET["link_review_id"];
```

Then use that in JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var link_review_id = "<?php echo $link_review_id; ?>";
        if(link_review_id != "" && link_review_id != null){
            var scroll_object = $("#resultsbox_" + link_review_id).offset();
            var scroll_height = scroll_object.top - 100;
            window.scrollBy(0, scroll_height);
        }
});
```

On a normal page load without the GET value set, the auto scroll down would be ignored.  If a GET value is set, I take the scroll to length of the DIV in question and take 100px off of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a margin + padding which counteract each other:

```
.resultsbox {
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This makes the the resultsboxes overlap each other on the list